# ANDROID usage of Jackson library: How to load object with indexes - range from to

Tags: java, android, json, performance, jackson

I have really big JSON file for parsing and managing. My JSON file contains structure like this

```
[
{"id": "11040548","key1":"keyValue1","key2":"keyValue2","key3":"keyValue3","key4":"keyValue4","key5":"keyValue5","key6":"keyValue6","key7":"keyValue7","key8":"keyValue8","key9":"keyValue9","key10":"keyValue10","key11":"keyValue11","key12":"keyValue12","key13":"keyValue13","key14":"keyValue14","key15":"keyValue15"
},
{"id": "11040549","key1":"keyValue1","key2":"keyValue2","key3":"keyValue3","key4":"keyValue4","key5":"keyValue5","key6":"keyValue6","key7":"keyValue7","key8":"keyValue8","key9":"keyValue9","key10":"keyValue10","key11":"keyValue11","key12":"keyValue12","key13":"keyValue13","key14":"keyValue14","key15":"keyValue15"
},
....
{"id": "11040548","key1":"keyValue1","key2":"keyValue2","key3":"keyValue3","key4":"keyValue4","key5":"keyValue5","key6":"keyValue6","key7":"keyValue7","key8":"keyValue8","key9":"keyValue9","key10":"keyValue10","key11":"keyValue11","key12":"keyValue12","key13":"keyValue13","key14":"keyValue14","key15":"keyValue15"
}
]
```

My JSON file contains data about topics from news website and practically every day this JSON file will be increased dramatically.

For parsing of that file I use

```
URL urlLinkSource = new URL(OUTBOX_URL);
urlLinkSourceReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        urlLinkSource.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<DataContainerList> DataContainerListData = mapper.readValue(urlLinkSourceReader,new TypeReference<List<DataContainerList>>() { }); //DataContainerList contains id, key1, key2, key3..key15
```

My problem is that I want to load in this line

```
List<DataContainerList> DataContainerListData = mapper.readValue(urlLinkSourceReader,new TypeReference<List<DataContainerList>>() { });
```

only range of JSON object - just first ten object, just second ten object - because I need to display in my app just 10 news in paging mode (all the time I know the index of which 10 I need to display). It totally stuped to load 10 000 objects and to iterate just first 10 of them. So my question is how I can load 
in similar way like this one:

```
List<DataContainerList> DataContainerListData = mapper.readValue(urlLinkSourceReader,new TypeReference<List<DataContainerList>>() { });
```

only objects with indexes FROM -TO (for example from 30 to 40) without loading of all objects in the entire JSON file?

Regards

Comment: paging mode really is a bad practice. put that in a loader, this way you load when asked for it.

Comment: The problem here seems to be with your datastructure or the fact that the API (if any) you use to get the JSON is very rigid.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of what you mean by "load object with indexes from to", if you want to

**Read everything but bind only a sublist**
The solution in that case is to read the full stream and only bind values within those indexes.
You can use jacksons streaming api and do it yourself. Parse the stream use a counter to keep track of actual index and then bind to POJOs only what you need.
However this is not a good solution if your file is large and its done in real time.

**Read only the data between those indexes**

You should do that if your file is big and performance matters. Instead of having a single big file, do the pagination by splitting your json array into multiple files matching your ranges, and then just deserialize the specific file content into your array.

Hope this helps...

Comment: thank you for your answers...I would like to share the solution with you - I did one bridge php page which I call by parameters (page numver) in my android apps. This the php I did all needed filer actions for generation of limited json file from the exact page